# Conditional Probability using Venn Diagrams

Tags: probability

In class we have been told (for now) to use Venn diagrams to solve probability questions, we were also set this question for homework. Instead of answers, a tip, or a nudge in the right direction would be help me the most.

Two events $A$ and $B$ are such that $P(A) = \frac{1}{3}$ and $P(B) = \frac{1}{2}$. Calculate $P(A'\cap B)$ when:

i) $P(A \cap B) = \frac{1}{8}$.

ii) $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive

iii) $A$ is a subset of $B$

Here's my working for part i)

$P(A'\cap B) = P(B) - P(A\cap B)$

$\therefore P(A'\cap B) = \frac{3}{8}$

Part 2, and three are more elusive, though. I know mutually exclsuive means they can't both happen at the same time. Does this mean it's $\frac{2}{3}$, or $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: To use LaTeX here you need to put $ signs around the markup

Comment: @Henry Thanks, I've got a hold of the syntax, thanks to your edit.

Comment: For (i) and indeed all of them it is $P(B)-P(A\cap B)$ without the complement prime mark, so I have removed it from your working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the probability of the intersection of $A'$ and $B$, so it cannot be bigger than $P(B)$

In fact for (ii) it is $\frac12$

For (iii): $A \subset B \implies A \cap B = A$

Comment: I made a typo, it should be $\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: For part (iii), it is $P(A \cap B) \therefore \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{6}$. I think that's correct.